# NullPointerException in GORM 6.1.10

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am upgrading from GORM 6.1.9.RELEASE to 6.1.10.RELEASE to remedy the following:

https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1072

I have come across another problem, where my getter in my domain class is not getting invoked on a null field.

Take the example domain class:

```
class Factory {

    String name
    Factory primaryFactory

    static constraints = {
        primaryFactory nullable: true
    }

    Factory getPrimaryFactory() {
        primaryFactory ?: this
    }
}
```

Now take the following code in Bootstrap.groovy where a Factory is created with primaryFactory set to NULL:

```
def init = {

    def testFactory = new Factory(name: 'Test Factory').save()

    assert Factory.count() == 1
}
```

When I create the following TestController, testFactory.primaryFactory.name is not being rendered in GORM 6.1.10.RELEASE while it is in 6.1.9.RELEASE:

```
class TestController {

    def index() {
        Factory testFactory = Factory.findByName('Test Factory')
        println "Primary Factory: $testFactory.primaryFactory.name"
        render 'Check Console'
    }
}
```

The following error is being output:

```
2018-09-17 12:34:22.161 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException 
occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/index
Cannot get property 'name' on null object. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
at com.mycompany.myapp.TestController.index(TestController.groovy:7)
... 14 common frames omitted
```

Below is a sample github project also, to re create simply change the GORM version in gradle.properties from 6.1.9.RELEASE to 6.1.10.RELEASE:

https://github.com/georgy3k/gorm-6.1.10-NullPointerException

EDIT:

I also don't seem to be able to explicitally call the getter either. When I try to do so in this code:

```
class TestController {

    def index() {
        Factory testFactory = Factory.findByName('Test Factory')
        String testFactoryPrimaryName = testFactory.getPrimaryFactory().name
        println "Primary Factory: $testFactoryPrimaryName"
        render 'Check Console'
    }
}
```

This outputs the following error:

```
2018-09-18 11:47:40.837 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/index
Cannot get property 'name' on null object. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
at com.mycompany.myapp.TestController.index(TestController.groovy:9)
... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your Hibernate is using field access, not property access.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this or how do I configure that? Apologies if this is widely available ...

Comment: You can set `accessType` to `javax.persistence.AccessType.PROPERTY`.  See http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#upgradeNotes.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown, that has solved my problem. Was there any particular reason as to why the default has changed from property access to field access? Performance related or something like that? Just wondering in case there might be detrimental effects by setting my application to use property access.

Comment: Also, it seems as if I can't explicitly call the getter anymore either, updating the question with details. Is there something I'm missing in config for this?